# Efficiently encode reference to element in multidimensional array into a string

Tags: javascript

I am writing JavaScript function that creates HTML elements based on elements from multidimensional array. Once the HTML elements are created, I would like to be able on some element event, to update it's originating element in the array, but I can't easily get reference to it. I guess the answer is to encode reference to array element into HTML element's id, but every attempt I made becomes overly complicated.
Any suggestion?

```
var arr = [1,2,[5,2,7]];
container = document.getElementById('container');
createHTMLElements(arr);

function createHTMLElements (arr) {
    var x;
    for (x in arr){
        if (typeof arr[x] !== 'object'){
            listItem = document.createElement("li");
            text = document.createTextNode(arr[x]);
            listItem.setAttribute("id", "EncodedRefToArrayElement");
            listItem.appendChild(text);
            container.appendChild(listItem);
        } else {
            createHTMLElements(arr[x]);
        }
    }
}

function getRef(EncodedRefToArrayElement){
    //decode reference here
    return variablePointingToArrayElement;
}
```

Comment: It's not easy because you can't create a reference to an index.  Your best bet is to build some kind of lookup string/array/object that you can later use to find the array element.  Your recursive function would need to build that lookup based on the "path" to the element via its ancestors in the array. I would not set the id of the element to the lookup, rather use an attribute like "data-lookup".  Also please don't use `for...in` to iterate an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not that far from a workable solution. The reference into a multidemensional array is just a list of numbers, and you need to associate that with the element. That is what `data-` attributes are for.

```
var arr = [1,2,[5,2,7]];
container = document.getElementById('container');
createHTMLElements(arr, []);

function createHTMLElements (arr, lastLookup) {
    // make a copy of your lookup list and append a new level
    var lookup = lastLookup.concat([0]);

    arr.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        // set the last lookup number to the current index
        lookup[lookup.length - 1] = index;
        if (typeof elem !== 'object'){
            listItem = document.createElement("li");
            text = document.createTextNode(elem);
            // serialize your lookup array
            listItem.setAttribute("data-lookup", lookup.join(","));
            listItem.appendChild(text);
            container.appendChild(listItem);
        } else {
            createHTMLElements(elem, lookup);
        }
    });
}
```

To have a function that "gets a reference" to an array element would look a bit awkward. Since your entries are of a primitive data type, you cannot pass them by reference. You would need two bits of data, a reference to the innermost array *plus* the index pointing inside.

What you want is to change a value in your array, you can do it in one go:

```
function changeItem(listItem, value){
    // deserialize your lookup to an array again
    var lookup = listItem.getAttribute("data-lookup").split(",");
    var lastId = lookup.pop();
    var part = arr;
    // step into the data array
    lookup.forEach(function (index) {
        part = part[index];
    });
    // since tha last level was popped off, ref now
    // points to the innermost array
    part[lastID] = value;
}
```